# Regular Expression to find string and set as variable

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that will tell me if a string has `{0#}` where zero can be repeated. Once I confirm that a string has this I am then trying to set it to a variable so I can count the number of 0s and replace the # with another number. I have `/([{0]})([#}])/g` which works on detection but not on pulling it out to another variable.

Edit:
Thanks to all, the answer was

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\{(0+)(#)\}");
    Match match = regex.Match(text);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        int zeros = Regex.Matches(match.Value, "0").Count;
    }
```

Comment: `([{0]})([#}])` does NOT work for detection of `{0#}` as it simply does not match `{0#}`. Not sure what you are trying to explain here. Perhaps give two or three concrete and different examples of input strings together with the expected outcome (please make the examples easy to understand), so we get a better idea of what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
\{(0+)(#)\}
```

character {

then one or more occurance of 0

a # sign

character }

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FyQuxZ/1)

Answer (score 1):

You are super close. The problem you are having is because your capture group - the `( )` needs to be just around the zeroes. You also don't strictly need the other capture group unless you are doing something with it. You can rewrite your regex like this:

```
{(0+)#}

{       - match '{'
 (0+)   - match and capture one or more '0'
     #  - match '#'
      } - match '}'
```